# Retrieving data out of post success from separate controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

I am writing a simple service that uploads a file and posts it to a Spring controller. The controller manipulates this data and returns several objects as JSON.
I am working with the following Angular service:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', [ '$http', function($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);

            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest : angular.identity,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : undefined
                }
            })

            .success(function(data) {
                console.log("upload successful")
                //console.log(data)
                namesandaddresses = data;
            })

            .error(function() {
                console.log("upload error")
            });
        }
    } ]);
```

I have a separate controller in the code that I want to use to post this data (namesandaddresses) to the view and use ng-repeat to display the information. My struggle right now is pulling the data outside of this success function, let alone the service itself. I have tried creating a global var namesandaddresses outside the service so that I can access it from another controller but it shows up as undefined.

From my research I have found the appropriate way to do this is to use a callback function but my attempts to write this into the service breaks the basic function. Before stepping back to redesign this service or reconsidering my approach I wanted to post this and see if the stackoverflow community could help me tweak this service so that I can post this JSON to the view upon success.

Would someone lend me a hand?

Comment: You can inject this service in your controller and return something from the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy.

### Controller:

```
fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl (file,uploadUrl, {
            successCallBack: yourSuccessHandler,
            failureCallBack: yourFailureHandler
        });

function yourSuccessHandler(data) {
            $scope.data= data; 
        }

function yourFailureHandler() {
            console.log("Failed Messge printing from Controller"); 
        }
```

### Service

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', [ '$http', function($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, options) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);

            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest : angular.identity,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : undefined
                }
            })

            .success(function(data) {
                console.log("upload successful");
                if(options && options.successCallBack) {
                    return options.successCallBack(data);
                }
            })

            .error(function() {
                console.log("upload error");
                if(options && options.failureCallBack) {
                    return options.failureCallBack();
                }
            });
        }
    } ]);
```