# Passing Angular Factory variable into Controller

Tags: angularjs, websocket, angularjs-scope

How can I pass the websocket variable into the controller in order to send data back through the same websocket connection?

```
  app.factory('MyData', function($websocket, $q){
      // Open a WebSocket connection
      var dataStream = $websocket('ws://address');

      var collection = [];


       dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
       var data = collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data)); 
       var data = (JSON.stringify(collection));
       var data = Object(collection);

       // Check for requests to Delete posted Questions.

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var uuid1 = collection[i].uuid;
            // console.log(uuid1);

              for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                  var uuid2 = collection[j].uuid;
                  // console.log(uuid2);

                   if (i !=j){

                        if (uuid1 == uuid2){
                          console.log("Delete Question Request for uuid: " + uuid1);
                          collection.splice(i);
                          collection.splice(j);
                      }
                        else console.log("No Questions to Delete");
                    }
              }
        }

      });

       //Function that returns data from websocket and parses into JSON Array

      var methods = {
        collection: collection, 
        get: function() {
          dataStream.send({ action: 'get' });
        }

      };


      return methods;

    });
```

My controller has the function joinChatRoom() that I'm trying to send data back through the same open websocket connection.:

```
    app.controller('WaitingRoom', function ($scope, $websocket, MyData) {

      $scope.MyData = MyData;
      console.log(MyData);



      $scope.joinChatRoom = function(uuid){

          var code = "code";
          var uuidTitle = "uuid";
          var chatRequest  = {};
          chatRequest[code] = 100;
          chatRequest[uuidTitle] = uuid;

          var sendChatRequest = JSON.stringify(chatRequest);

          // send request to join chat room.
          dataStream.send(sendChatRequest);

      };


});
```

Comment: $websocket is not a standard AngularJS service. Please include a link to the library that provides $websocket.

Comment: **too broad**
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My apologies, new to angular. I'm using the following websocket library:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket

Comment: I figured if I can pass the variable from the Factory to the Controller, I can use the same open connection to send data back.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have some sort of a getter function in your factory that gets the data...
All you have to do is inject your WebSocket service into the scope of your controller, and you should be able to call the getter function, which does the rest.
  .controller(')

Comment: I added the rest of my code, hoping that helps . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send callbacks from controller to your factory while calling:

Check my answer on this question:

[Retrieving data out of post success from separate controller angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087118/retrieving-data-out-of-post-success-from-separate-controller-angularjs/45087386#45087386)